# Repair a Hole/Crack in Hollow Core Door

Tags: repair, doors, hole, hole-repair

Someone punched a hole/crack in my hollow core door. I was wondering what my best course of action would be? Would it be relatively cheap/not too difficult for me to try and fix it myself? I looked at a few other similar questions to mine but the hole/crack in my door looks different than the ones in the questions that others have posted. Here are a couple pictures of the door:

[image]
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you prepared to paint the door - so it no longer looks like wood?

Comment: I'd buy a new door.   These hollow-core doors are cheaper than you think and weigh almost nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repair it but you're not going to be able to match the wood decor grain - which means you'll have to paint it.
There are a few different products you can use but I like Bondo. It's basically the same stuff they use for auto body repair. It looks like there is enough backing in the hole that you shouldn't need anything but the Bondo, a putty knife and a few sheets of sandpaper. Apply it according to directions trying not to overfill it too much since you'll want to sand it smooth with the door. After it dries start with about a 120 grit sandpaper or sanding block to take off most of the excess and finish with a 220 or higher grit to finish. If there are any hollows in the patch you can apply more Bondo after it's dry. It will be difficult to get the patch to totally disappear but with patience and going over it a few times you can get it very close.
It's hard to tell the material in the picture but you may need a good prime coat to get the adhesion and consistency you'll want with the paint.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Do you have any advice on how I could go about finding the right paint color to match the original finish? I was thinking I could cut off a piece of the broken wood and take it to home depot to get it color matched but after reading your answer it seems like I would remove whatever backing is left in the hole if I was to cut into it.

Comment: Just to be clear, I would paint that entire side of the door. That way you don't have to match it exactly - you could paint it white if you wanted. If you want to match it you could take a piece of the splintered wood. You just want to have some material, even crumpled newspaper inside the door as a backer for the Bondo.

Comment: Got it, thanks again for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: When I worked in a door factory we used Bondo (well, the Australian version) to repair dented hardboard skinned doors. a bit of filler, a bit of sanding, spray-can primer and back into stock.

Answer (score -1):

You asked for advice on color matching.  Turns out there's an app for that!
See https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-choose-pick-the-right-paint-color-for-your-home-walls/ for a rundown on your options.